# Parsing result of URL.getHost()

Tags: java

Need help parsing...

In my code, I have a method that returns url.getHost();. But the results of that can be blarg.com, or sometimes dates.blarg.com. I want to return blarg.com for either situation (or for xxx.yyy.ggg.blarg.com).

I can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

EDIT: getHost() is from java's built in class java.net.URL.

Comment: Everything is possible in Java but you need to show getHost()

Comment: I'm using java's built in class java.net.URL. It includes the getHost() method I'm using.

Comment: @user618712 - how do you intend to handle cases like `www.amazon.co.uk`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String host = url.getHost();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^.+[.]([^.]+[.][^.]+)$").matcher(host);
if(m.matches()) {
  host = m.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using split:

```
String host = url.getHost();
String[] items = host.split("\\.");
if(items.length>2)
   host = items[items.length-2] + '.' + items[items.length-1];
```

Using indexes:

```
String host = url.getHost();
while(host.indexOf('.')!=host.lastIndexOf('.')) {
  host = host.substring(host.indexOf('.') + 1);
}
```

Comment: your second example only handles 1 extra dot.  OP wants a solution for 1 or more extra dots.

Comment: @jtahlborn - If you actually run the code you'll see that it does.

Comment: oops, missed that you were looping, thought it was a single if.